# Downloadable link for MS Access file

Tags: asp-classic

**I am stuck in creating a link for ".mdf" MS-Access file through which the file can be downloaded**. I have gone through many similar questions and their answers but no luck. I tried to use anchor tag in simple html file but didn't work.

Later I tried classic asp script, but that also not worked. Classic ASP script is given below

```
<%
const adTypeBinary = 1


    'Set the content type to the specific type that you are sending.
     Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream"
     Response.AddHeader "Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=labels.mdf"

     set objStream = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
     objStream.open
     objStream.type = adTypeBinary
     'objStream.LoadFromFile(strFilePath & strFile)
     objStream.LoadFromFile(server.MapPath("labels.mdf"))

    response.binarywrite objStream.Read

    objStream.close
    Set objStream = nothing

%>
```

Note: We are using classic ASP as a server side language, so you consider if necessary in example.

Comment: Please edit the question and describe what *does* happen

Comment: Why not just use the request filtering module to allow IIS to serve .mdf files.

Comment: you want to download the access file which is on your server?

Answer (score 0):

I think because the mdf file is being used. As I know *.mdf is sql server database file.. so Its impossible to get "it" as long as SQL server is running and serve the related database. this is my suggestion :

1. Detach the related database
2. Make sure you have read access to the related folder